# Trying to get a variable to work in mvc/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

So pretty much I'm trying to get a list from my Model.Customer.Details.Sorts to be placed in a HTML.TextArea....within a Div called 'SortBox'.

```
for (i = 0; i < data["Sorts"].length; i++) {
                        //         alert("In loop")
                            $('#SortBox').append('@Html.TextArea("Comment", Model.CustomerDetails.Sorts[i])')
                        }
```

however i'm currently getting this error.

```
the name 'i' does not exist in the current context
```

Any help to get this working would be much appreciated.  Please and thank you

Comment: Actually this is almost closer to my goal
`$('#SortBox').append('@Html.TextBox("Sortboxs", "data['Sorts'][i]" )');`
as it gives a '<input> tag...however the value is turning up to be "data['sorts'][i] instead of say 1. Apple and then another 2. Bannana

Comment: `@Html.TextArea()` is razor code and is parsed on the server before it is sent to the view. `i` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point. Why are you using javascript for this instead of generating the textareas on the server?

Comment: I know they are...however I'm using it because this is within a for loop trying to get each item from the Sorts Model List. Also because I'm quite noobish this the only way I can think of generating enough input box's with the variables from a  list from a Model.

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quote before the @:

$('#SortBox').append(@Html.TextArea("Comment", Model.CustomerDetails.Sorts[i]))